# How to determine number of neighbors in knn in pycaret

Tags: python, knn, pycaret

My question lies specifically in knn method in
[Anomaly Detection module](https://pycaret.org/anomaly-detection/) of pycaret library.
Usually number of k neighbors has to be specified. Like for example in PyOD library.

How to learn what number of neighbors knn uses in pycaret library?
Or does it have a default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the number of neighbors of the constructed knn model by printing it.
By default, **`n_neighbors=5, radius=1.0`**. 
I run the knn demo code locally, with:

```sh
python=3.6
pycaret=2.2.3
vscode
```

```py
import pycaret
from pycaret.anomaly import *
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
anomaly = get_data('anomaly')
exp_name = setup(data = anomaly)

knn = create_model('knn') 

print("pausing") # set breakpoint here
```

In debugging mode, I get:
[image: default knn para in pycaret]

**Further**, you can set the parameter when call `create_model`, e.g. set the number of neighbors as 10:
[image: set knn]